# gedit extensions for programming

Tags: gedit

I like to use gedit for my C++ and Python programs. While the default language settings are rather impressive, I was wondering if there are any quality extensions I can install that enhance the language features inside gedit? Thank you.

Comment: For full-fledged programming, I'd recommend a full code editor like [Geany](https://www.geany.org/) or [Atom](https://atom.io/)

Answer (score 4):

By default gedit has a few useful plugins (most of all, *Snippets* and *Python console*)

The following packages give a lot of good plugins:

- `gedit-plugins`
- `gedit-developer-plugins`

The list of plugins which the above provide:

- Bookmarks
- Bracket completion
- Character map
- Code comment/uncomment
- Color picker
- Color scheme editor
- Commander ("Command line interface for advanced editing")
- Tab Dashboard
- Draw spaces and tabs
- Embedded Terminal
- Find in files
- Git integration
- Bazaar integration
- GDP word completion
- Join/split lines
- Smart spaces
- Word completion
- GDP format
- Multi edit (like [part 1 and 2 of this Sublime Text demo](https://www.sublimetext.com/))